# How to align images to the right?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use css to put some images this way:

```
|_________<img1_1>|___<img2_1>|
|                 |<___img2_2>|
|                 |__<_img2_3>|
```

All the images should be align right and i cannot use a fixed width size because the size of the images may vary.

Image img1_1 is to the left off all the others (but still align right of the page).

plz help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with CSS

set all images float to right
for images 2_2 and 2_3 set `clear:right`

If it's supposed to be a layout - consider using DIVs to create regions on the page.

Create a content div and put another 2 divs in it. Set float of one of them to right and give it a width. Set a margin on the other one. Put images in them.

Comment: Very good! clear:right was what i had been missing. I was already getting paranoid by trying lots of things that didn't work. ty very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Using a `float: right` with an `inline-block` should work fine.

`float` can, in some rare cases, produce varying results accross browsers, however it works well 99% of the time.

James

Comment: Didn't work. img2_1, 2_2 and 2_3 stay together if there is enough space. I'm using firefox 3.6.12.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the images in a div tag add a class or an id and set the class/id to **text-align: right;** or float all the images to the right **.class img { float: right; }**

Comment: text-align only worked when i put text instead of images and for images inside divs img2_1, 2_2 and 2_3 stay together if there is enough space.