# Right-align block elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'd like to right-align block elements in a floating container.

Assume the following markup.

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <img style="display: block;" src="...">
  <img style="display: block;" src="...">
</div>
```

```
   current                 wanted
+-----------+          +-----------+
|+-------+  |          |  +-------+|
||       |  |          |  |       ||
||       |  |          |  |       ||
|+-------+  |   --->   |  +-------+|
|+----+     |          |     +----+|
||    |     |          |     |    ||
|+----+     |          |     +----+|
+-----------+          +-----------+
```

What I've tried:

- `div { text-align: right; }` - works in IE8, fails in Firefox (naturally, the images are blocks and not supposed to be affected by `text-align`)
- `img { margin: 0 0 0 auto; }` - works in Firefox, fails in IE8
- floating the images to the right - does not work as I never want the images on the same line. Also, floated images no longer push down the following content.

What else can I try? I prefer a pure CSS solution, if that's at all possible.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle that explains the full markup: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/yCTHX/3/

Setting `float: right;` works for all real browsers, for IE8 it extends the image box in the row first over the entire width and pushes down the box with the text.

Comment: set the div `text-align: right;`?

Comment: @Ms.Nobody Oh come on.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4377203/211627

Comment: I guess the answer can't be that easy if the person asking has 123k rep :D

Comment: why not combine the two and use both at the same time?

Comment: Which doctype do you use? Isn't IE8 in quirks mode? In standards mode, there should be no problem with `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` solution.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody It's not the amount of rep. It's that I've said that I already tried `text-align: right;`. It's really not *that much* text in my question.

Comment: It's more text than code :D that means it's a lot of text :D sorry.. trying to workout your solution somehow and stay amused at the same time...

Comment: If you set your images as inline elements `text-align: right` would work.

Comment: @Ennui Yes, but then there's a chance that they end up on the same line and I don't want that.

Comment: "images are blocks and not supposed to be affected by text-align" sorry?

Comment: IMO, krike's solution below seems to be what you want.

Comment: I don't understand. You are using text-align on the wrong element. It should be set on the container, and not on the children elements.

Comment: @notme You are right, that was a mistake on my part when I typed the question. It's already corrected.

Comment: I updated again.. I hope this is what you want. [**IE8 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/yCTHX/5/show/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
div > img { float:right; clear:right; }
```

Comment: Read the OP's question "floating the images to the right - does not work as I never want the images on the same line. Also, floated images no longer push down the following content.
"

Comment: Yes, that works for all modern browsers, but unfortunately it does not work in IE. See my question update. +1 anyway, because that's a clean solution.

Comment: @Tomalak no, it will not work in IE, not in that layout. Same goes for the `:nth-child` selectors. You can try putting `direction:rtl` on `(odd) .box` rows, but personally I'd go javascript at this point, because it's a lot more time efficient.

Comment: With [`ie9.js`](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) a surprising amount of CSS starts to work even in old IEs. That's what I'm using to get `:nth-child()` to behave, but it might have an adverse impact in some other place.

Comment: @Tomalak we're deviated a bit from the original question.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to align an element with CSS is to set text-align on the container and margin on the children elements.
Your tries are wrong since you are setting margin and text-align on the img tag.  Your css should look like:

```
div {
float:right;
text-align: right;
}
img {
margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

Just tested on ie8, ff and chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/notme/wfwjf/2/

Comment: Floating the images to the right widens the container `<div>` over the entire page in IE. There are two floated containers next to each other (one with the images, one with text). They are supposed to be one the same line, in IE the `float` pushes the text container to the the next line. :-/

Comment: Regarding the `text-align`, you are absolutely right. That's what I've been trying, the question text is wrong in this regard. Correcting.

Comment: why are you floating both containers? you should float just the first one, no?

Comment: This is a valid question, I'll try floating only one (i.e., the image-) container.

Comment: Nope, that does not work as it affects the fixed-width text block next to the images (see http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/yCTHX/6/ in comparison to http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/yCTHX/4/).

Answer (score 2):

> use clearfix hack, this will help you to not to float bottom img next to top img. 
>   height width can be define as you wish

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
.main_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
.big_img {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.small_img {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main_div">
    <img src="" class="big_img">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <img src="" class="small_img">

     </div>
```

Here is the [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/SMq7C/)

Comment: That's not the clean solution I had in mind - I want to avoid adding more markup to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to edit the HTML.. but if you want images to be in block why don't just put them in one :D!

### HTML

```
    <p>This is crap station train to the mainstream...</p>        

    <div class="sth">
    <p><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0ada184c98bf9073d15b2dc815be0170?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="jesus was not" /></p>
    <p><img src="http://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/9d699fb41cafd14479fbd1ae1c89c669?s=128" alt="mum asked me to" /></p>
    </div>

    <p>This is crap station train to the mainstream...</p>
```

### CSS

```
.sth{display:block; text-align:right;}
.sth img{ 
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/zBnqQ/39/

Comment: Pragmatic solution. I want to avoid adding more markup, but it might be that I end up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a div aligned right:

```
<div style="float: right;">
  <div align='right' class='content-container'>
    <img class='image1' style="display: block;" src="..." />
    <img class='image2' style="display: block;" src="..." />
  </div> 
</div>
```

Then use js to set the width of the div to the image:

```
$('.container').width($('.image1').width());
```

CSS:

```
.image1 {
    width: 50px;
}
.image2 {
    width: 30px;
}
```

Though it is better with js it is not necessary for it to work

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GuTZ3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent div of the images. It will wrap around the images when you float them, and clear the images from the right with `clear: right`

http://jsfiddle.net/zBnqQ/15/

Comment: using `overflow: auto` will be better instead of `overflow: hidden`. because we don't know whether OP wants to hide the extra content or not. (and also could be more helpful to visitors)... :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions one with basic HTML attribute:
Approach 1:

```
<p>
<img src="...." align="right">...some text...
</p>
```

Approach 2:
You can use Column based layouts using http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com

Col 1      Col 2
text..     image

Answer (score -2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/rtaUj/4/

CSS

```
.image1 {
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 0;

}
.image2 {
    width: 100px;
   border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;

}
```